# Download image from skipper-gridfs in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, gridfs

I upload images to server with gridfs in my sails.js Application. My uploading codes are as follows

```
upload: function  (req, res) {
        req.file('avatar')
            .upload({
                adapter: require('skipper-gridfs'),
                uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname.images'
            }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
                if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
                else return res.ok({
                    files: uploadedFiles,
                    textParams: req.params.all()
                });
            });
    }
```

I get the following response from this...

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "fd": "2d8910a0-8ca2-4df1-9930-6ddd721a0416.jpg",
            "size": 172883,
            "type": "image/jpeg",
            "filename": "Photo on 12-20-14 at 9.53 PM.jpg",
            "status": "bufferingOrWriting",
            "field": "avatar",
            "extra": {
                "fileId": "54aee6ced4a0e88f0dc9025f",
                "fd": "2d8910a0-8ca2-4df1-9930-6ddd721a0416.jpg",
                "dirname": "."
            }
        }
    ],
    "textParams": {}
}
```

My question is , if I need to download the uploaded file above , what shall I do ? I got the following code in the internet for downloading task but this does not make much sense to me. Basically I want the download url of the uploaded image that I can use that url in Mobile App to show image.

```
var blobAdapter = require('skipper-gridfs')({
            uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname.images'
        });
        blobAdapter.read(filename, callback);
```

Can anybody help me on this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

After some research, I finally managed to solve the problem. I get the field `fd` in the response after file upload and save that to use afterwards. I went to the `skipper-gridfs` codes and found a `'read'` method that accept that value and returns the required file. So, I just pulled that file from mongo by that method and send as a response. It's working file.

```
download: function (req, res) {
        var blobAdapter = require('skipper-gridfs')({
            uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydbname.images'
        });

        var fd = req.param('fd'); // value of fd comes here from get request
        blobAdapter.read(fd, function(error , file) {
            if(error) {
                res.json(error);
            } else {
                res.contentType('image/png');
                res.send(new Buffer(file));
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope it will help somebody like me in the future :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing-- this is exactly the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's great too see creator of Sails.JS here appreciating my effort :)

Comment: I wonder if it is important/necessary to create a new Buffer in `res.send()`, since [concat-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-stream) (which skipper-gridfs uses) returns a buffer for binary data?

Comment: Is it possible to make `res.contentType('image/png');` dynamic to pass in any file type (PDF, xls, .doc etc)? @mikermcneil

Comment: @Ayon @Robert Rossmann Sorry guys, I should have been more clear- I didn't see the tail end of the example originally.  I'd recommend using the streaming approach rather than loading the entire file in memory when downloading it. (i.e. omit the cb)

So, instead of the callback, you can do `var gushingStream = blobAdapter.read(fd);  return gushingStream.pipe(res);`

For context, here's an example of the implementation of `read` in a skipper adapter: https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper-disk/blob/764c0729181285b84ef43b71820050fa33dcc4a5/index.js#L47-L53

Other than that, looks great!

Comment: @mblais29 definitely can do a dynamic content type in the response, but you'll need to have your code figure out what kind of file it is some way.  Usually, what I've found I end up doing is storing additional metadata for each uploaded file in the database (in the form of a record for each file uploaded-- e.g. in an `UploadedFile` model (best to avoid using `File` as the name of the model b/c it's reserved).  Then, when uploading, I store the content-type that the file was uploaded with, and fetch it again before downloading.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Ayon's excellent answer above, here's a version of the same code that demonstrates streams, persisted file metadata, a dynamic content type, and a couple of other related comments:

```
download: function (req, res) {

  if (!_.isString(req.param('fileId') && !_.isNumber(req.param('fileId')){
    return res.badRequest('`fileId` should be provided as a string/number (depending on whether this is Mongo or MySQL, if you\'ve customized the primary key, etc.).');
  }

  // Look up file metadata
  UploadedFile.findOne({ id: req.param('fileId') })
  .exec(function (err, fileRecord) {
    if (err) { return res.serverError(err); }
    if (!fileRecord) { return res.notFound(); }

    // Get configured blob adapter instance.
    var blobAdapterOpts = _.omit(sails.config.fileUploads, 'adapter');
    var configuredBlobAdapter = sails.config.fileUploads.adapter(blobAdapterOpts);

    // Now locate the actual raw contents of the file using the
    // `fd` that we saved elsewhere (i.e. when uploading), and then
    // use the blob adapter to open up a stream of bytes (the file's
    // contents) and pipe that down as the HTTP response body.  
    // (like skipping a rock across the surface of a pond)
    var fileStream = configuredBlobAdapter.read(fileRecord.fd);
    fileStream.on('error', function (err){
      return res.serverError(err);
    });

    // Along the way, set the content-type for the response based on
    // whatever we saved when this file was originally uploaded.
    // 
    // (You could do the same thing for the filename, assuming this
    // file download is the "save as" kind, as determined by the
    // content-disposition header.)
    res.contentType(fileRecord.contentType);

    // Pipe the stream of file data through as our HTTP response body.
    // (like skipping a rock on the surface of a pond)
    return fileStream.pipe(res);

  });

}
```

#### Why the stream?

This streaming approach saves us from loading the entire file into
memory on our server (which would other become a problem when
dealing with large files, or with many concurrent downloads)

#### The error handler

Since we're dealing with a raw Node stream/emitter in userland
code here, we must be sure to bind an 'error' event handler
before doing anything-- just in case.  (This prevents any
unexpected stream errors from crashing the process.)

#### "open" vs. "save file as"

You could use a request parameter as a flag to determine how
to set the content-disposition header -- and thus whether the
user's browser/device/native app should "open" vs. "save as"
the file.

#### Custom config

This example demonstrates setting up some custom config.
e.g. in config/custom.js, you might put:
    module.exports.custom = {
      fileUploads: {
        adapter: require('skipper-fs'),
        uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydbname.images'
      },
    };

#### What about actions2?

If you're using actions2 (available in [Sails v1.x](https://sailsjs.com/upgrading) and up), you can accomplish the same thing as `res.pipe()` ~~and the related error handling~~ by simply passing through the stream directly to `exits.success()`.  *(**EDIT:** Actually, I was wrong about the 2nd part of that-- just [verified](https://github.com/sailshq/machine-as-action/blob/36bce6080305a7562e97c54252b5163093d46900/index.js#L797-L801) that still have to handle `.on('error',...)` yourself.)*   Also, you'll still have to set the content type response header; i.e. `env.res.contentType(fileRecord.contentType)`.